# How to avoid using multiple "if then" for checking parameters?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, performance

I have some code that should do a simple thing :

if the value of the parameter is -1 then I should change the value.
else - do nothing

I have a list of 20 parameters, but I wanted to know if there is any way of checking it without doing :

if param1 == -1 then ... else...

if param2 == -1 then.... else...

anyone has any idea what can I do to make it more efficient ?
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If parameters are all variables (it's not in array or something), you can make a function and write

```
change_or_let_it_be( &param1, value );
change_or_let_it_be( &param2, value );
change_or_let_it_be( &param3, value );
```

and there you have only one if (in function) and a lot of calls.
Better would be to store it in some structure (array, list etc) and avoid calling this function 20 times.

Comment: Wouldn't you either need to pass a pointer to the function arguments or return the potentially updated value?  i.e. Either `change_or_let_it_be(&param1, value)`  or `param1 = change_or_let_it_be(param1, value);`

Comment: It's only a hint, of course it needs to be really changed somehow.

Comment: It would be clearer to the OP any answer included working code.  Could you update it to use one of the options I suggested?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I'm understanding what you want, but how about this?

```
void func(int params[20]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        if (params[i] == -1)
            params[i] = NEW_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Checks every value with a for, so you don't need to hardcode all the different values, and then changes the parameter when it's -1. Also note that I'm supposing with "efficient" you mean more code-writing-time efficient here!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the series of if/then statements is the most efficient, if not the prettiest solution! Embedding the tests in a loop and storing the parameters as an array requires the following additional calculations:

```
- testing that the loop counter does not exceed the maximum
- incrementing the loop counter
- using pointer arithmetic to access each parameter
```

Of course these speed considerations are only a factor if you have to perform those 20 tests man many times. But in fact you've already written it as efficiently as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Another cleaner solution:

```
int *p[] = {&param1, &param2, &param3, NULL};
int i = 0;
for(;p[i] != NULL; i++) {
    if(*p[i] == -1) *p[i] = SOME_VALUE;
}
```